# Can't log into certain websites with Chrome, but it works with Firefox

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I use Chrome 36.0.1985.143 m on Windows 7.

Sometimes when I try to log into certain websites using Google Chrome, I get sent back to the original login page with empty username and password fields.

I can access the same websites successfully from Firefox.

I regularly delete my cookies.

Comment: No idea about the specific problem, but I regularly run into websites that don't play well with Firefox (I know that's not your problem). The web is (and should be) unregulated and people put all sorts of things in web pages that don't comply with current standards and best practices. I just keep 5 different browsers around and usually, one of them works. I usually fall back to Opera when Firefox can't handle something. You can probably debug and maybe even find a way around 1 problem at a time, but it's easier to try different browsers.